# angular 8 refresh token using interceptor

Tags: angular, jwt, angular8, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to implement refresh token feature using angular interceptor. Here is the stepwise procedure I am following

1. Store access token in local storage. Add this token to the authorization header.
2. If the access token is expired send the refresh token (stored in the database) and generate a new token.

In the following code, I am trying to implement the same. But the problem is when the access token gets expired current HTTP request doesn't get executed (gives 401 error). I have to reload that page for that HTTP request to work. How can I avoid this?

interceptor.ts

```
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  
  constructor(private router: Router, private loginService: LoginService) { }
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const jwt = localStorage.getItem('token')
    if (jwt) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`
        }
      });
    }
    if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
      request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
    }
    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          let errorMessage = '';
          if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
            // client-side error
            errorMessage = `${error.error.message}`;

          } else {

            // console.log(error)
            switch (error.status) {
              case 401: {
                console.log(error.error.error.message)
                console.log(error)

                if (error.error.error.message.includes('jwt expired')) {
                  console.log(true)
                  this.handle401Error(request, next)

                }
                else {
                  console.log(false)
                  this.router.navigate(['login'])

                }
              }
              default:
                //window.alert(error.error.error.message)
                return throwError(error);
            }
            // server-side error
          //  errorMessage = `${error.status}\n ${error.message}`;
          }
          //\  window.alert(errorMessage);
        //  return throwError(errorMessage);
        })
      )
  }

  private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    console.log('refresh token')
    const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refreshtoken')
    console.log(refreshToken)
    this.loginService.refresh_token(refreshToken)
      .pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
        localStorage.setItem('token', data.accessToken)
        const jwt = localStorage.getItem('token')
        console.log('401', jwt)
        if(jwt) {
          request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`
            }
          });
        }
        
        if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
          request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
        }
        return next.handle(request);

      })
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't get why you guys always want to implement all this stuff by yourself. Did you consider using `angular-oauth2-oidc`? It even allows you to do a silent refresh approach.

Answer (score -1):

you can use s.th like this:

```
getposts() {
return this.http.post<any>(`${config.apiUrl}/post`, {
  'type': 1
}).pipe(
  tap(() => this.doLogoutUser()),
  mapTo(true),
  catchError(error => {
    if(error.status===401){
    return this.http.post<any>(`${config.apiUrl}/post`, {
  'type': 1
     });
    }
  }));
}
```

also add tis line to catch error of interceptor to throw error:

```
return throwError(errorMessage);
```

so you can retry request send in catch error of your http.post without reload page